# Size in MB of mnesia table

Tags: erlang, elixir, mnesia

How do you read the `:mnesia.info`?

For example I only have one table, some_table, and `:mnesia.info` returns me this.

```
---> Processes holding locks <--- 
---> Processes waiting for locks <--- 
---> Participant transactions <--- 
---> Coordinator transactions <---
---> Uncertain transactions <--- 
---> Active tables <--- 
some_table: with 16020    records occupying 433455   words of mem
schema         : with 2        records occupying 536      words of mem
===> System info in version "4.15.5", debug level = none <===
opt_disc. Directory "/home/ubuntu/project/Mnesia.nonode@nohost" is NOT used.
use fallback at restart = false
running db nodes   = [nonode@nohost]
stopped db nodes   = [] 
master node tables = []
remote             = []
ram_copies         = ['some_table',schema]
disc_copies        = []
disc_only_copies   = []
[{nonode@nohost,ram_copies}] = [schema,'some_table']
488017 transactions committed, 0 aborted, 0 restarted, 0 logged to disc
0 held locks, 0 in queue; 0 local transactions, 0 remote
0 transactions waits for other nodes: []
```

Also calling:

```
:mnesia.table_info("some_table", :size)
```

It returns me 16020 which I think is the number of keys, but how can I get the memory usage?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#table_info-2), it’s [number of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)), meaning if you are on modern machine, it’s `16_020 * 64 / 8 = 128_160` bytes ≈ `128K`.

Comment: _some_table: with 16020    records occupying_ **433455** _words of mem_  : You have to know the size of a word on your machine (probably 64, maybe 32 bits)

Comment: Is that term "word" which confuses me, not sure how to know it's size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need `mnesia:table_info(Table, memory)` to obtain the number of [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) occupied by your table, in your example you are getting the number of items in the table, not the memory. To transform that value to MB, you can first use `erlang:system_info(wordsize)` to get the word size in bytes for your machine architecture(on a 32 bit system a word is 4 bytes and 64 bits it's 8 bytes), multiply it by your Mnesia table memory to obtain the size in bytes and finally transform the value to MegaBytes like:

```
MnesiaMemoryMB = (mnesia:table_info("some_table", memory) * erlang:system_info(wordsize)) / (1024*1024).
```

Comment: Can you give a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829549/mnesia-high-memory-usage there seems to be a high difference between table size and actual binary memory usage (mnesia is storing strings)

Comment: I suspect that a * is missing from the formula:


MnesiaMemoryMB = (mnesia:table_info("some_table", memory) * erlang:system_info(wordsize)) / (1024*1024).

Comment: Please be careful. If your table use `disc_only_copies`, the `mnesia:table_info` return the number of bytes stored on disc so you dont need to get the `wordsize`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `erlang:system_info(wordsize)` to get the word size in bytes, on a 32 bit system a word is 32 bits or 4 bytes, on 64 bit it's 8 bytes. So your table is using 433455 x wordsize.

Comment: Can you give a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829549/mnesia-high-memory-usage there seems to be a high difference between table size and actual binary memory usage (mnesia is storing strings)